# Can I breach a non-disclosure agreement if I share a story, but do not identify any of the parties involved?

Tags: united-states, california, non-disclosure

Assume that any details in the story would not enable anyone outside the story to infer the identities of the parties involved.

The agreement is a standard NDA between me and a former employer that I signed when I started working there.

Is there a way I can tell my story without violating my NDA?

Comment: Better to assume that the previous company will know exactly who shared the story. Will save you lots of time, money and aggravation.

Comment: @gnasher729 Yes, I already assumed that. That is not my question; the issue you raised is completely tangential.

Comment: You are going to need a lawyer to tell you the specific extent of the NDA you signed, but personally if it quacks like a duck... if the story you tell has any bearing on reality, discloses any details of real events covered under NDA, then its likely to be very murky water.  NDAs generally dont have an exception for fictionalised disclosures.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to add details, since it is unclear whether the story you intend to disclose is within scope of the NDA. If it is out of scope of the NDA, it might not even matter whether you disclose also the names of the parties involved.

Comment: There's not a "standard" NDA: it's going to depend on the terms of the contract. This can't be answered without a lawyer evaluating the contract and the story.

Comment: Thanks, guys. @RyanM I just mean that it is substantially similar in it's overall nature to other contacts that I have signed with other companies. I know that doesn't tell you exactly what it says. Part of the problem is that I don't have a copy of the contract, but I am working on that.